# Angular component not showing template

Tags: angular

I downloaded angular form https://angular.io/quick-start and then added a file to the app folder "tutoriel.component.ts" and wrote the following code

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'tutoriel',
    template: '<h2>Tutoriel</h2>'
})
export class TutorielComp{
    
}
```

and then changed this in the app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TutorielComp
  ],
```

and the class got imported
import { TutorielComp } from './tutoriel.component';
The problem is when I deleted all the code in the app.component.html and wrote

```
<tutoriel></tutoriel>
```

It did not show.

Comment: everything seems to be ok - did you get any errors ?

Comment: No, but I moved the folders to an another place and Vs code made them green all except the angular folder I dunno why

Comment: If you inspect the page from the browser's developer tab, do you see the selector tutoriel in the html?

Comment: No, I do not see it